# Is there a difference between [usersettings] and [user-settings]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

So, we have [usersettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usersettings) with 81 questions and [user-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-settings) with 31 questions. The latter has no wiki. Can we synomize these? It seems to me that this is exactly what this functionality is for. Two similarly named tags with identical meanings...

I would have suggested it myself, but I don't have enough answers on either of them to do so.

Comment: kinda wondering if we really need either of them.

Comment: Yeah, me too @KevinB. Now that you mention it.

Comment: I retagged the 4 questions that had **both** tags on them...

Comment: @rene *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title

> Is there a difference between [usersettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usersettings) and [user-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-settings)?

**Nope.** The tags appear to be duplicates, and we tend to prefer the hyphen-as-spaces variant in tags. So if we were to synonymise or re-tag them, that'd be tag to use.

But [Kevin B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204/is-there-a-difference-between-usersettings-and-user-settings#comment155870_286204) <sup>1</sup> made a good comment

> kinda wondering if we really need either of them.

To which I say, **we probably don't need either of them.** We already have [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings) for these kind of questions. [11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-settings+settings+OR+usersettings+settings) already have the tag!

So, I think **we should just burninate the tags** instead of making them synonyms. There are [only 110 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usersettings+OR+user-settings) and "settings" is already part of the tag. There also aren't many users meeting the rep limit on the tags, so it'd be quicker to re-tag them.

Just replace [user-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-settings) or [usersettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usersettings) with [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings) on each of the questions.

<sub>1. *A [different Kevin B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b).*</sub>

Comment: But why go through the effort of burning them when they will inevitably be re-created. I say make them both synonyms of the settings tag.

Comment: @RubberDuck I didn't mean for the tone to come across that way, my apologies. But you would have to wait for [a mod to create the synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71072/159034), as there aren't many users who could vote on it. And re-tagging questions which share both the source and destination tags to only include one is pretty standard, to prevent duplicate tags appearing on questions.

Comment: Clean ups come along with the territory. I'm just questioning the wisdom of burning tags that might (probably IMO) get recreated when a synonym would permanently solve the issue. Apology accepted btw.

Comment: @RubberDuck I'd highly recommend adding your own answer advocating for the synonym instead of burnination, that way a mod will be able to tell that there's an interest in a synonym against [tag:settings]. In either case, _I think_ it's possible to add the synonym after the fact (even if the tag has no questions) if it does become an issue.